# SHA256 giving unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, sha256, hashlib

I'm trying to use hashlib to hash a byte array, but I can't get the hash to match what I am expecting (by confirming the answer with online SHA256 functions).

Here's how I'm doing the hash:

```
hashedData = hashlib.sha256(input[0:32]).hexdigest()
print('hash = ', hashedData)
```

Before I do the hash, I print out the hex digest for the input data:

```
print('input = ', input[0:32].hex())
```

[image: Here's an example output.]

When I compare with several online sha256 functions, the output doesn't match. For this example, the correct hash should be:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: rather than posting screenshot of hex input and output, post them as text

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data being hashed in your code appears to be a byte string, but the data you hash on whatever online tool you are using is your `.hex()` result, which is ASCII hexadecimal values.  They are not the same thing.  See below for a comparison that reproduces both of your results:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
import hashlib

data1 = b'ff815ef617d058df5d16f96a73591e4d12ac358cc113a8c74d8f4ac5843dd921'
data2 = unhexlify(data1)
print(f'{data1=}\n{data2=}')
hashed1 = hashlib.sha256(data1).hexdigest()
hashed2 = hashlib.sha256(data2).hexdigest()
print(f'{hashed1=}\n{hashed2=}')
```

Output:

```
data1=b'ff815ef617d058df5d16f96a73591e4d12ac358cc113a8c74d8f4ac5843dd921'
data2=b'\xff\x81^\xf6\x17\xd0X\xdf]\x16\xf9jsY\x1eM\x12\xac5\x8c\xc1\x13\xa8\xc7M\x8fJ\xc5\x84=\xd9!'
hashed1='e417268832671b04efa73ba4093572975e084b8b33bfdcb4f9345093f80106ff'
hashed2='56e8d96c55150870ecc84c9a355de617993e21e29c9edcf3caa369b252fd2108'
```

Comment: That makes sense. So I am doing the hash correctly then? How can I verify the output?

Comment: i found an online function that accepts byte strings (https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm), and it looks like the hash is correct - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to give encoded input to sha256. Input must be passed as a bytestring. Use `encode()` method to convert it to bytestring format.

```
hashed = hashlib.sha256("test".encode()).hexdigest()
print(hashed)
```

In your case use bytes() method to encode your byte array:

```
hash_input=bytes(input)
```

Result: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

[Actual res from](https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) :9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08